# How to use NodeJS Streams to query Multiple DBs from a generic Function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, stream, nodejs-stream

I have Nodejs Project which reads data from several databases (db info and queries to execute are provided via config file) and uploads it as csv to S3. Now the problem is that the data can be very very large, hence the need to use streams to avoid memory usage explosion. This can be done for any db easily, an example for mysql is given below:

```
connection
.query('SELECT * FROM TABLE')
.stream({ highWaterMark: 5 })
.pipe(someFunction);
```

However, this is a mysql specific implementation. I need to design the code in such a way that the main function calls out a standard library function called say "queryGeneric". This queryGeneric Function takes an argument of dbType and then calls the db-specific function. How can I use streams for this queryGeneric Function?

An example of queryGeneric Function is as follows:

constants.js

```
DB_FUNCTIONS = {
'MYSQL' : 'mysql.js',
'MSSQL' : 'mssql.js
}
```

genericDbFunctions.js

```
function queryGeneric(connection, dbName, statement, callback) {
    var dbFxns = require(constants.DB_FUNCTIONS[dbName]);
    var data = dbFxns.query(connection, statement, function(err, results) {
        return callback(err, results);
    });
    }
```

mysql.js

```
function query(connection, statement, callback) {
    connection.query(statement, function(err, results) {
        return callback(err, results);
    });
}
```

Similarly there can be mssql.js or postgresql.js etc files that contain those db-specific functions. queryGeneric Function figures out the relevant function to call using the mappings provided in constants.js file.

Now my main.js will call out queryGeneric function as follows:
main.js

```
//code to read the config file
//loop start for each db in the config file
    var connection = getConnectionGeneric(dbName);
    queryGeneric(dbWrapper, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE', function(err, results){//Some action})

//loop end
```

The above main.js file is actually very pseudo-code like, written in such a way for the purpose of asking this question. The main.js actually loops a config file, reading specifications(connection info and query to run) from there and calling queryGeneric for each of the database.

How can I convert the queryGeneric function call to something like:

main.js

```
queryGeneric(dbWrapper, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE').stream({ highWaterMark: 5 }).pipe(someFunction);
```

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if more details or clarifications are needed.

Also, the someFunction in above snippet needs to be a function that uploads the data to S3. I am hoping that if the stream is implemented as expected, the upload function should be like the standard implementation of uploadToS3 function as provided everywhere. However, any pointers on that as well are appreciated.